# Reacting to changes in radio button on the client side of a Razor ASP.NET Core Page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to make a radio button on an ASP.NET Core Razor page control the appearance of another UI element without requiring a roundtrip to the server.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do, but with a roundtrip to server.

Running program looks like this:

[image: Running program]

Here is the relevant code:

```
// Test.cshtml
<h3 style="color:@Model.Color">Hello in @Model.Color</h3>

<form method="post">
    <input type="radio" asp-for="Color" value="red" />Red<br />
    <input type="radio" asp-for="Color" value="green" />Green<br />
    <input type="radio" asp-for="Color" value="blue" />Blue<br />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

// Test.cshtml.cs
public class TestModel : PageModel {
    [BindProperty]
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync() {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

In order for the text to change color, end-users must click [Submit]; I would like to avoid it. Please suggest a client-side solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this will be done client-side, you can use javascript.

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) are used to select elements from the DOM and operate using CSS style selectors.  Select the `radio` buttons and add an `onclick` event to each.  In the `onclick` event update the `h3` style and text.

The below snippet uses plain javascript. [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is another great tool I'd recommend for this kind of task.

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
for (radio in radios) {
    radios[radio].onclick = function() {
       var h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
       h3.style.color = this.value;
       h3.innerText = 'Hello in ' + this.value;
    }
}
```

```html
<h3 style="color:@Model.Color">Hello in @Model.Color</h3>

<input type="radio" asp-for="Color" value="red" />Red<br />
<input type="radio" asp-for="Color" value="green" />Green<br />
<input type="radio" asp-for="Color" value="blue" />Blue<br />
```